# Haskell function to replace variable in a string with its values. Like f-string (Python) or glue (R)

Tags: string, haskell

I want to replace replace in-place variable in string without using concatenation. I want some function

```
foo :: String -> [a] -> String
```

For example

```
values = [1, 2]      
foo "This is a {?} and this is test3 - {?}" values
```

Expected Output:

```
"This is a 1 and this is test3 - 2"
```

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more careful with types than this, and there's no syntax anything like that for a dictionary type. But overall, this is a reasonable exercise. What have you tried? What are the issues you're encountering?

Comment: Updated the question, this was my initial question, There was no hashmap in that, I used only as a sudo code.. I was bit confused on how to frame my question, now I think it is understandable .. Thanks.

Comment: Why is the expected output not `"This is a 1 and this is test3 - 2"`?

Comment: My bad, fixed it

Comment: The type signature should rather be something like `foo :: Show a => String -> [a] -> String`

Comment: This is simply not a thing in Haskell. This is because if `foo "{?}" [123]` type checks, so does `foo "{?}" [123,234]` and `foo "{?}" []`, turning compile-time errors into runtime ones, which makes us prefer the alternative. At best, you could leverage Template Haskell and craft a `foo` that can make `$(foo "{?} blah {?}")` into a function that accepts two arguments like `(\x y -> show x ++ " blah " ++ show y)` so that it will only handle the correct amount and type of arguments.

Comment: Why is this not just `Text.Printf`?  That's probably the best you're going to get, but you have to give up the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import Data.List ( transpose )

values :: [Integer]
values = [1, 2]     
 
foo :: Show a => [Char] -> [a] -> [Char]
foo xs vs = (concat . concat . transpose) [splitOn "{?}" xs, map show vs]

result :: [Char]
result = foo "This is a {?} and this is test3 - {?}" values

-- "This is a 1 and this is test3 - 2"
```

Note: "map show" converts the Integer type of values to strings.
"concat . concat" flattens the two level nested list.
"transpose" is working like zip here. Zip makes tuples instead of lists, so it doesn't flatten directly with "concat".

Comment: I actually had list of char so I needed not to use show.. Removing it and fixing few things according to need.  This solution works by the way.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The `streamEditT` function in [replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec-1.4.5.0) is designed so solve this kind of “replace variable in string” problem in a general way.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Text.Megaparsec.Char (string)
import Replace.Megaparsec (streamEditT)
import Control.Monad.State (State, evalState, get, put)
import Data.List (uncons)

foo :: Show a => String -> [a] -> String
foo input xlist = flip evalState xlist $ streamEditT pattern editor input
 where
  pattern = string "{?}"
  editor matched = do
    xs <- get
    case uncons xs of
      Just (headx, tailxs) -> do
        put tailxs
        pure $ show headx
      Nothing -> pure matched

foo "This is a {?} and this is test3 - {?}" [1,2]
```

```
"This is a 1 and this is test3 - 2"
```

Comment: This is very cool. I am having trouble getting it to compile for me though. Monadic parsers are definitely at the far edge of my knowledge. This is the error I get and don't know how to fix: Couldn't match type ‘Text.Megaparsec.Stream.Tokens s0’
                     with ‘String’
      Expected: megaparsec-9.2.1:Text.Megaparsec.Internal.ParsecT
                  e1
                  String
                  (Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT
                     [a] Data.Functor.Identity.Identity)
                  String
 No room for full error, but hopefully this is enough

Comment: Did you do the {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-} ?

Comment: Yes, I have: {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts, OverloadedStrings #-}